# PLSQL Passing n number of parameters to a procedure

Tags: plsql

Im doing an assignment and need a few ideas of how to answer this question:

*"Allow the user to add new orders by inputting n number of order items (where 2 ≤ n  ≤ 10) as parameters"*

My question is what can I use to pass in a various amount of parameters. I would then need to check inside whatever I am storing these in to test the amount of items (parameters passed) is > 2 and < 10

In order to insert a new order I will also need to get the user to input a Cutomer No and quantity amount of the items - Do these parameters need to be passed as the same time as passing the order item numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using an array, see below. You need to create the types and the procedure in the database , then run the script to see how it works. The p_tab_order.COUNT command can be used to work out how many orders you have.

```
CREATE TYPE  type_order AS OBJECT(item_number     NUMBER(6)
                                 ,customer_number NUMBER(6)
                                 ,quantity        NUMBER(6));


CREATE TYPE type_tab_order IS TABLE OF type_order;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_order(p_tab_order IN type_tab_order)
IS
BEGIN

    FOR i IN 1..p_tab_order.COUNT LOOP


    dbms_output.put_line(p_tab_order(i).item_number||' item number '
                       ||p_tab_order(i).customer_number||' customer_number '
                       ||p_tab_order(i).quantity||' quantity '
                          );


    END LOOP;


END;


DECLARE 

l_tab_order type_tab_order := type_tab_order();

BEGIN

l_tab_order.EXTEND;
l_tab_order(1).item_number := 4;
l_tab_order(1).customer_number := 5;
l_tab_order(1).quantity := 6;

l_tab_order.EXTEND;
l_tab_order(2).item_number := 5;
l_tab_order(2).customer_number := 6;
l_tab_order(2).quantity := 7;

p_order(p_tab_order => l_tab_order);


END;
```

Comment: I got this working. Rather than using the tables I already had with the REFs in I used your code above to create another object with the columns I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this.  I'll assume, for purposes of example, that for each order you need a customer number and a purchase order number.  In which case you could do:

```
PROCEDURE ADD_A_BUNCH_OF_ORDERS(CUST_NUM_1  IN NUMBER,
                                PO_NUM_1    IN NUMBER,
                                CUST_NUM_2  IN NUMBER,
                                PO_NUM_2    IN NUMBER,
                                CUST_NUM_3  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_3    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_4  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_4    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_5  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_5    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_6  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_6    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_7  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_7    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_8  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_8    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_9  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_9    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                CUST_NUM_10 IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                PO_NUM_10   IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
BEGIN
  ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_1, PO_NUM_1);
  ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_2, PO_NUM_2);

  IF CUST_NUM_3 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_3 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_3, PO_NUM_3);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_4 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_4 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_4, PO_NUM_4);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_5 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_5 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_5, PO_NUM_5);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_6 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_6 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_6, PO_NUM_6);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_7 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_7 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_7, PO_NUM_7);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_8 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_8 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_8, PO_NUM_8);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_9 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_9 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_9, PO_NUM_9);
  END IF;

  IF CUST_NUM_10 IS NOT NULL AND
     PO_NUM_10 IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    ADD_ORDER(CUST_NUM_10, PO_NUM_10);
  END IF;
END ADD_A_BUNCH_OF_ORDERS;
```

You then just need to implement the ADD_ORDER procedure to add the particular order given.

Perhaps not the most elegant way, but **A** way.  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: thank you for you help. this has gave me an idea. I will allow the user to input a number into the program that will tell the procedure how many items the user wants to add to an order. I will then create a loop to ask for that amount of items and save to the variables. Will post once done. Thank you

Comment: Couldnt get my idea working. Apparently you cant get user input at runtime of a procedure. Strange!

Comment: PL/SQL executes in the server, and is not interactive in the way that you're looking for there.